# What is the best way to ban/block users with Devise for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, registration, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication in my rails app and I'd like to be able to block certain accounts and prevent users from reregistering with a blocked email. I'm just not sure what the best way is to go about it.

My first thought was to override the sessions and registrations controllers to check the model for a user with a blocked bit, but I have a feeling there might be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.banned?
    sign_out resource
    banned_user_path
  else
   super
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this has a weakness: if a user is banned while they are already logged in, the ban won't take effect until they sign out and sign back in again (which could be a long time.) So either force the user to log out at the time when you ban them, or move this logic to a `before_action` in your controllers instead of using `after_sign_in_path_for`.

Comment: when you ban the user, just add one more line to log him out

Answer (score 31):

The best approach is to do it in **Devise way**:

*Below assumes that you are using Devise database_authenticatable module and your application's users model names User.*

**1. Implement an *account_active?* method.**

Add boolean `account_active` column in users table or define `account_active?` method in User model (you can chose your own method name). For example:

```
    # app/models/user.rb
    def account_active?
      blocked_at.nil?
    end
```

**2. Overwrite the `active_for_authentication?` method in your model (User).**

```
    # app/models/user.rb
    def active_for_authentication?
      super && account_active?
    end
```

**3. Add method which returns translation for flash message.**

Whenever `active_for_authentication?` returns false, Devise asks the reason why your model is inactive using the `inactive_message` method.

```
    # app/models/user.rb 
    def inactive_message
      account_active? ? super : :locked
    end
```

And that's it. You don't need to care about `sign_out` or `redirect_to` user.

Moreover, user is locked immediately, with next request, not after next sign in.

More: [devise/authenticatable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb).

Comment: Please would you tell what is each file for each code block?

Comment: @AymanSalah done as requested. All three methods needs to be placed in `app/models/user.rb` (assuming that user.rb is your model responsible for the application's users)

Comment: Worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to override the active_for_authentication? method on the devise model (User). Like so:

```
    def active_for_authentication?
      super && !self.banned?
    end
```