# Extra login field for Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails app I use Devise for authentication. Now I want to extend the login screen with an extra field where the user needs to fill in a value only he knows, like the date when he started at the company or something.

How can I add this extra check, besides the regular email and password fields, to the Devise authentication check process?

I read something about the `active_for_authentication?` which you can extend in the User model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && special_condition_is_valid?
end
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Edit: In the end I have overwritten the SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User) && !resource.correct_token?(params[:user][:security_token])
      sign_out resource
      flash[:error] = I18n.t('.devise.failure.invalid_token')
      root_path
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

This was inspired on the solution here: [Rails + Devise - Is there a way to BAN a user so they can't login or reset their password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629480/rails-devise-is-there-a-way-to-ban-a-user-so-they-cant-login-or-reset-their)

The only issue I have left is that when an invalid token is submitted, both the success and error message are visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simple generate the views:

```
bundle exec rails generate devise:views
```

This will copy the devise views into your app/views folder.
After that you can modify the app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb file and extend it with your form fields.

After that you can overwrite the devise controller.