# PostgreSQL check whether timestamp field is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454032/how-to-stop-soft-deleted-users-login-with-devise?rq=1) to check whether a user has been soft-deleted or not when logging in. In the example below I can check for a boolean value:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
    super(conditions.merge(:deleted_flag => false))
  end
```

I would prefer a timestamp (created_at) field. How can I check whether such a field is empty? The database throws errors for the following checks:

```
super(conditions.merge(:deleted_at => false)) # also tried nil, "NULL" and "IS NULL"
```

Comment: Did you try `:deleted_at => None` or `none`?

Comment: Thanks, didn't work, it says `undefined local variable` or `undefined constant`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't using this solution, without modifying devise of course. Devise will send your conditions directly to the database, so no way of calling a method or using a library like squeel (that will allow something like `where{created_at == nil}`.

You could use the solution provided in [How to "soft delete" user with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140643/how-to-soft-delete-user-with-devise/8107966#8107966), but the error message will be: "You have to confirm your account before continuing."

Add this to your resource model:

```
  def inactive_message
    !!deleted_at ? :deleted : super
  end
```

And add a message to your locales:

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      deleted: "Your account was deleted."
```

I hope it helps!