# Force user logout with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a controller filter that should logout a user if their account is expired, but I can't figure out an easy way to do it.

I tried:

```
if user_signed_in? && current_user.status == 'expired'
  redirect_to destroy_user_session_path
end
```

But the above doesn't work, because Devise wants a DELETE action on the logout path, so you can't just redirect to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`active_for_authentication?`**

After authenticating a user and in each request, Devise checks if your model is active by calling model.active_for_authentication?. This method is overwritten by other devise modules. For instance, :confirmable overwrites .active_for_authentication? to only return true if your model was confirmed.

You overwrite this method yourself, but if you do, don't forget to call super:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && special_condition_is_valid?
end
```

Look at the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable) to find out more details and an example. This [doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in) will also help you.

Comment: Thanks, this almost gets me there. The problem with this is that I can't distinguish between a user that hasn't yet been confirmed (I use confirmable) and a user that's inactive for another reason (expired/suspended/etc). Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out- you just have to override `inactive_message` on the user for the correct condition- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14966003/165673